# session_start No funciona

Tags: mysql, html5, php7, atom-editor

Intento utilizar session_start pero no funciona como debe, al copiar el url y pegarlo en otro navegador me permite el acceso a lo que se supone debe estar restringido por el mismo.

```
    if ($numero_registro!=0) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["logeo"]=$_POST["login"];
    }


    <?php
    session_start();
    $varsesion = $_SESSION['logeo'];

    if($varsesion == null || $varsesion = '' ){
    header("Location:index.html");
    die ();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Perdona, copie mal el codigo, ya lo corregi, gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: Las sesiones no funcionan de esa forma, `session_start();` solo debe ir una vez en la cabecera, con ello podrás utilizar la(s) variable(s) `$_SESSION['logeo']` en todos los documentos que tengan `session_start();`. Saludos.